# Accessing variables in local scope and adding them to global scope in Julia

Tags: scope, julia, global

Any possibilities to access local and global scopes and manipulate these. Maybe something similar to this python example:

```py
def foo():
    x = 10
    globals().update(locals()) # update global parameters

print(x) # continue using x
```

I would like to do this without using `global` for variables individually.

Comment: No I don't want to use the ```global``` keyword individually for a variable. It's more about how to access the data structures of the scopes and manipulating them. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This seems like there is definitely a better answer for whatever you want to do.

Comment: @Oscar Smith I'm actually trying to execute julia code as a string from python and only want to manipulate the code to a minimal extent. But in the end I am just curious. This question is not about best practices. I am aware that this is bad programming style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's @MarcMush's answer as a macro:

```
julia> macro horribile_dictu()
           return quote 
               for (name, value) in Base.@locals()
                   eval(:(global $name = $value))
               end
           end
       end
@horribile_dictu (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand let x = 1
           @horribile_dictu()
       end
:(let x = 1
      #= REPL[29]:2 =#
      begin
          #= REPL[28]:3 =#
          for (var"#3#name", var"#4#value") = $(Expr(:locals))
              #= REPL[28]:4 =#
              Main.eval(Core._expr(:global, Core._expr(:(=), var"#3#name", var"#4#value")))
          end
      end
  end)

julia> let x = 1
           @horribile_dictu()
       end

julia> x
1

julia> function foo()
           x = 10
           @horribile_dictu()
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()

julia> print(x)
10
julia>
```

To repeat: avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like quite bad programming but here is a way to do this, with the `@eval` and [`Base.@locals`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@locals) macros (`@eval` evaluates in global scope)

```
julia> function f(a,b)
           c = a*b

           for (k,v) in Base.@locals
               @eval $k = $v
           end
       end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(2,3)

julia> a
2

julia> b
3

julia> c
6

julia> f("a", "b")

julia> a
"a"

julia> b
"b"

julia> c
"ab"
```